# conversion failed when converting date from character message

Tags: sql-server

I receive a file monthly that for some reason has service_date as a char(8) data type. The image shows some of the things that are entered and the second column is the length of the service date field. Is there a way for me to clean up the bad dates? I was hoping if the length was shorter or longer I could eliminate them but it doesn't seem like it will work. Any ideas on what the best way to fix this field would be. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Start by explaining how you would fix a value like "M1921175 ". That has 8 non-whitespace characters - so how would testing the length be of any use? You can use try_convert as suggested, but then what? You should think carefully about what the file **should** contain and whether rows should or should not be imported based on appropriate validation logic. Don't just ignore or cover up the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to attempt to convert your `Service_Date` values into a `date` and excluding any where a `null` is returned.